# How to scale to a specific variance in an AR(2) process

Tags: matlab, variance

I have an AR(2) process output `Z(t) = a*Z(t-1) + b*Z(t-2) + u(t)` where u(t) is additive white Gaussian noise. How do I make the Variance of the output observation `Z` to 1?

Comment: Do you want the variance of Z(t) generated by the process to be one or do you want the variance of the next Z(t) to have a variance of 1 ?  Also, do you want to generate you white noise and then rescale it or do you want the white noise to produce the right variance ?

Comment: Is this not more of a question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @LucBerthiaume: The variance of the entire process after the last sample is generated, should be 1. I think this depends on the variance of the noise which controls the var of Z. I am not so sure if noise variance should be rescaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the process Z(t) = a*Z(t-1) + b*Z(t-2) + c * u(t) is stationary (check here http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/uts/lec2-08.pdf),

```
c = sqrt(1-b^2-a^2*(1+b)/(1-b))
```

Matlab code:

```
Nt = 1000; Nseries = 10000; 
Zt = zeros(Nt,1); varZ = zeros(Nt,1);
a = 0.95; b = -0.195; c = sqrt(1 - b^2 - a^2*(1+b)/(1-b) );

for i = 1 : Nseries
z = zeros(Nt,1);
z(1) = randn(1);  z(2) = randn(1);
for t = 3 : Nt
    z(t) = a * z(t-1) + b * z(t-2) + c * randn(1); 
end
Zt(i) = z(Nt);
varZ(i) = var(z);
end

% variance at time point Nt
var(Zt) 

%distr of variance estimator
[y,x] = hist(varZ,20);
bar(x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the formula. But, the true values of the coefficients a = 0.95 and b= -0.195. So, if I use this formula then I no longer can generate the process with the actual coefficients.

Comment: I see, one sec, i'll adjust an answer

Comment: Thank you, however there is a typo I think : You mistakenly wrote (1-b^2) in the numerator. Instead it should be (1-b)^2

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're right, let me check tonight from home

Comment: I re-checked the formula and did the substitution myself I ran the code and the Var(Z) is not exactly coming out to be 1; it is sometimes 0.8724 or 0.9145 etc  on each independent run. Thank you for your time in checking it for me.

Comment: Apologies, couldn't come back to it earlier. I checked the formula and it gives me the correct answer. The confusion might come from your expression for Var(Z). Do you take it as E(Zt^2), i.e. taking many realizations of Z at the same time point t?

Comment: (A) I did not take many realizations of Z at the same point,; I have generated 10 time series - Z1, Z2 etc and for each realization I calculated the var(Z1), var(Z2). Then, RandomInput =  Mean+ sqrt(c)*randn(1,N); Z1(t) = a*Z1(t-1) + b*Z1(t-2)+ RandomInput(t);

Comment: (B) I have used the formula given under point (8) : var(Z1) = ((1-b)*c^2)/((1+b)*((1-b)^2 - a^2)). So, I think (1-b)^2 term is missing in your answer. Please correct me if wrong. Lastly, I shall really appreciate if you can mention info whether there is a formula for higher order models or how to apply this for higher order model.

Comment: Exactly, and using var(Z1) = 1 gives you expression for c. I still think my expression is correct :).

Comment: You can take one of the books on the timeseries with discussions of the ARMA models.  E.g., take a look here http://www.xycoon.com/arp_process.htm

Comment: Just posted test Matlab code. I think you use a small sample from var distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your continued support and the code. I used a small sample size of 250 data points. Thank you for your answer.